# What benefits do you gain from playing the Guild Wars 2 beta?

Tags: guild-wars, guild-wars-2

I know you get a 3 day headstart - but in gears 3 for example, you got special skins for the weapons if you played the beta. Are there similar rewards?

Comment: You get the 3 day headstart for *pre-ordering* the game, not for  playing the beta. Is that what you meant - 'what do you get for pre-ordering the game'? As far as I know there aren't any rewards for participating in the beta

Comment: The 3 day headstart is only for **pre-purchase**, not **pre-orders**. Pre-order only gets you a 1 day headstart.

Comment: At work atm, don't have time but I'll do it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no tangible benefits to playing the beta. If you have pre-purchased you'll get a 3 day headstart on retail release.

There are a few benefits to playing in the beta's in that you can learn the game so that upon release you can hit the ground running with your choice of race and class.

As for actual tangible items these are linked to playing Guild Wars 1 in the Hall of Monuments. By earning points in GW1 you'll unlock items which can be used in GW2.

http://hom.guildwars2.com is used to show how many points you've accrued on your GW1 account.

Comment: I have a load of items and money in GW1, is this in any way transferable or worth anything?

Comment: @SirYakalot Yes, but you'll need to dedicate items which are dedicatable, and use the money to buy armour and dedicate that. It's all managed through the HOM. (http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Hom)

Comment: do you need anything special to get to the HOM? like a specific expansion pack or to have finished specific quests?

Comment: @SirYakalot To get access to the HoM you'll need Eye of the North, and to complete the very first quest in the expansion in order to reach [Eye of the North](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Eye_of_the_North_(outpost)) then you need to earn your Monument Tapestries by completing the primary EoTN quests. Then you can start dedicating items. Note the honour monument is unlocked by default. [More on Hom usage](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Hom#Usage)